# Golang interface on type

Tags: interface, struct, go

I am new to GO and I am using golang to write a simple type interface.
The type is defined as:

```
type Sequence []float64

and the interface is:

type Stats interface {

        greaterThan(x float64) Sequence
}
```

The function `greaterThan(x float64)` should return a new Sequence that is the same as the numbers in the object
        // except all numbers less than, or equal to, x have been removed.

Here is my try, but it will not compile. I don't know how to fix it.
My question is : how can I delete an item from structure type? Should I use a map? (as my try)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Sequence []float64

type Stats interface {

        greaterThan(x float64) Sequence
}

func (s Sequence) greaterThan(x float64) Sequence{

    var i int
    var f float64
    set := make(map[float64]int)
    var v = f[i] Sequence

    for i, f := range set{

    for j := 0; j <= len(s); j++ {
        if s[j] <= x {
        delete(set, s[j])
        }
    }
}

    return v
}

func display(s Sequence) {

        fmt.Println("s.greaterThan(2):", s.greaterThan(2))

}

func main() {

        s := Sequence([]float64{1, 2, 3, -1, 6, 3, 2, 1, 0})
        display(s)

}
```

Comment: What error messages does the compilation attempt show you?

Comment: BTW. as seen [here](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#delete) `delete` takes the map (in your case `set`), and the key (in your case `j`) as arguments. So the delete call would look like `delete(set, i)` not `delete(set, s[j])`

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it like this:

```
package main
import "fmt"
type Sequence []float64
type Stats interface {
    greaterThan(x float64) Sequence
}

func (s Sequence) greaterThan(x float64) (ans Sequence) {
    for _, v := range s {
        if v > x {
            ans = append(ans, v)
        }
    }
    return ans
}

func main() {
    s := Sequence{1, 2, 3, -1, 6, 3, 2, 1, 0}
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", s.greaterThan(2))
}
```

See http://play.golang.org/p/qXi5uE-25v

Most probably you should not *delete* items from the slice but construct a new one containing only the wanted ones.

Just out of curiosity: What do you want to do with the interface Stat?